# Dropdown with margins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown with languages at top left of the page. The problem is that when the mouse hovers over this margin the menu slides up. Could someone tell me how to avoid such an effect? Here is the link - http://livedemo07682.prestatrend.com and here is the code:

```
//Block languages module
    $('#languages_switcher').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('#languages_block_top span').addClass('hover');
        $(this).find('#first-languages').stop(true, true).slideDown(300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('#languages_block_top span').removeClass('hover');
        $(this).find('#first-languages').stop(true, true).slideUp(150);
    });
```

Comment: Are you talking about 1em space between menu and the panel which slide down ? Then simply remove "top: 1em" from #first-languages_wrapper in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
#first-languages_wrapper {
    /* top: 1em Remove this line */
    bottom: 4px; /* Add this one */
}
```

**EDIT:**

That's happening because the margin area is outside of the `#languages_switcher` boundaries. You have two options.

1. Instead of `top: 1em` in your menu, put `padding-bottom: 1em` in `#languages_switcher`.
2. Remove `top: 1em` and replace it with `border-top: 1em solid transparent`

Comment: No I need exactly this margin I need a dropdown a lil bit down from the orange switcher.

Comment: The currency menu has this...Why do you need the margin I don't get it>?

Comment: No I do not need it like at currency I need it like now at languages a lil bit down 1em at my case...

Comment: I see, I edited my answer...Still don't know why that inconsistency in the design I mean the currency menu looks better without that space.,..

Answer (score 0):

add padding to the element

```
#languages_switcher {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: But in this case when hovering on #languages_switcher and a space
under it 1em dropdown will slide down... not good looking...

Comment: In this case just hover under #languages_switcher and you will see that menu is slide down.

Answer (score 0):

Reading over your comments i take it that you do want that 1em drop from your language switcher and your dropdown menu, though i can't see why, it looks unpolished and inconsistent with the rest of your nav bars but here is a fix.

Instead of dropping your submenu by using `top:1em` just drop it with some padding-top, this way you can stretch down the container along its axis and that margin drop won't affect the hover event;

**CSS**

```
#first-languages_wrapper {
   padding-top:1em;
}
```

Though i would recommend you drop it by `top:100%` instead, looks more cleaner.

Comment: Yes, it's looks more cleaner but does not clean at all coz after padding-top: 1em there is a space under #languages_switcher and if you hover on the space under it menu will slide down it's not good looking do you understand?

Comment: I think the best way is to make a little time out what do you thin folks?

Comment: @Anton just noticed that, you can remove that extra bit of padding by using a negative margin on the bottom of your `#languages_switcher` div, like so: `margin-bottom:-1em`.